# Wordpress PHP 5.5 and OPcache

Tags: cache

I have tried to run on my Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.5 OPcache. My admins turned it on for me but the site was not faster - it was slower.

Is there a how-to somewhere or a code snipet needed in WordPress to make it work?

Googling gave me nothing. The most interesting thing is why on my VPS the site with OPcache was running slower. What did I/we do wrong...

Edit:
The hosting admins have told me that OPcache runs on stock settings but unfortunatelly they haven't told me what they are. My luck is that BPS Pro plugin has an option to see various settings and here they are:

```
Zend OPcache
Opcode Caching  Up and Running
Optimization    Enabled
Startup         OK
Shared memory model     mmap
Cache hits      0
Cache misses    1
Used memory     5466264
Free memory     61642600
Wasted memory   0
Interned Strings Used memory    401208
Interned Strings Free memory    3793096
Cached scripts  1
Cached keys     2
Max keys        3907
OOM restarts    0
Hash keys restarts      0
Manual restarts         0

Directive       Local Value     Master Value
opcache.blacklist_filename      no value        no value
opcache.consistency_checks      0       0
opcache.dups_fix        Off     Off
opcache.enable  On      On
opcache.enable_cli      Off     Off
opcache.enable_file_override    Off     Off
opcache.error_log       no value        no value
opcache.fast_shutdown   0       0
opcache.file_update_protection  2       2
opcache.force_restart_timeout   180     180
opcache.inherited_hack  On      On
opcache.interned_strings_buffer 4       4
opcache.load_comments   1       1
opcache.log_verbosity_level     1       1
opcache.max_accelerated_files   2000    2000
opcache.max_file_size   0       0
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   5       5
opcache.memory_consumption      64      64
opcache.optimization_level      0xFFFFFFFF      0xFFFFFFFF
opcache.preferred_memory_model  no value        no value
opcache.protect_memory  0       0
opcache.restrict_api    no value        no value
opcache.revalidate_freq 2       2
opcache.revalidate_path Off     Off
opcache.save_comments   1       1
opcache.use_cwd On      On
opcache.validate_timestamps     On      On
```

Comment: What value do you have for `opcache.revalidate_freq`? Is there enough memory for the cache? This isn’t really WordPress related I think.

Comment: @toscho Depends. If the OP tries to figure out _why_ it is slower (instead of "give me snippez, fix asap"), then it is.

Comment: Jusyt updated the OP with requested data.

Comment: It's peculiar, WP does immensely benefit from opcode and doesn't need anything special to make use of it. Hard to guess from merely being slow though.

Comment: On what basis are you determining the site is slower? Have you ran repeated tests using load testing tools?

Comment: @jeffatrackaid for testing I use pingdom tools and gtmetrix - on pingdom a location in Amserdam as it is the closest to me. I have tested it thorough the day telling the admins to turn OPcache on and off and the difference was about 8-10% in favor of running WITHOUT OPcache. That is why I have started this thread :) I ahev also asked them to put the settings from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224798/how-to-use-php-opcache/17224811#17224811 this also didn't help